# Newtosoft Json Deserialization: How to throw an error if/when the given json string has MORE properties than necessary?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

Assuming we have the following class:

```
public class Foo {
      public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

How can we tell newtonsoft json to throw a tantrum if a given json-string is:

```
{ "Id": 10, "SomethingIrrelevant": "Foobar" }
```

In other words we want the deserialization to be ultra-strict and throw a tantrum when it detects anything fishy of this sort taking place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I make a strict deserialization with Newtonsoft.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096427/can-i-make-a-strict-deserialization-with-newtonsoft-json)

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15253875/4685428). Answer does not do exact what you want, but allow you to check if there was an extra fields after deserialization

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`MissingMemberHandling.Error`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm#MissingMemberHandling) for your `JsonSerializerSettings`:

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(jsonString,
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error
    }); // throws with "Could not find member 'SomethingIrrelevant' on object of type 'Foo'."
```

You can also force it to throw if `Id` is *not* present using a `JsonProperty` with [`Required.Always`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_Required.htm):

```
public class Foo {
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I had already employed 'MissingMemberHandling' but I thought it was doing what the 'Required = Required.Always' was doing (while it was the other way around). Do you by any chance know of a way to enforce 'Required = Required.Always' via the 'JsonSerializerSettings' for all deserializations? Thank you twice Jeff!

Comment: Excellent! It would have taken days for me to find this gem! Thanks a billion!